# Should videos associated with a question be embedded or should a hyperlink be provided instead?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I'm not entirely sure can videos such as YouTube videos be embedded in a question so I'm going to include once in this question.

Should videos be embedded into the question or would this make the question too bulky and be better served with just a hyperlink to the video?

Comment: According to this question embedding YouTube clips is only available on Music and Gaming. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66397/provide-a-way-to-embed-videos-in-answers/104189#104189

Comment: Well that answer did predate this site, but it is still true that we can't embed YouTube links.

Comment: So far they don't like enabling the embedding for beta sites far as i know unless absolutely necessary.  I'll ping around and see what I can dig up.

Comment: Out of curiosity: is there a *great* argument out there in support of this? I'm trying to think of one myself, and I'm not sure where I stand TBH, but this is only worth pursuing (IMHO) if there is a decent argument in support of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Poking around a bit with some other sites mods the consensus for video embedding is this:

In order to get video embedding on the site, we must start a meta discussion, siting existing questions that would greatly benefit from this feature and make a strong case to have it enabled.

So essentially, until we can convince the team that we need this feature, all you can do is hyperlink.